# How to create an explicit interface declaration index property with CodeDOM

Tags: c#, interface, indexing, codedom, explicit-interface

I am trying to create an explicit interface declaration index property.  So for example:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    int this[int i]
}

public abstract class Foo : IFoo
{
    int IFoo.this[int i]
}
```

I have written the following bit of code to do so (this works for normal index properties, but not for explicit interface declaration index properties):

```
var iface = typeof(IFoo);
var method = iface.GetMethod("Item"); // get the indexer

CodeMemberProperty memberIndexer = new CodeMemberProperty();

memberIndexer.Name = iface.Name + ".Item";

memberIndexer.Type = new CodeTypeReference(method.ReturnType.Name);
memberIndexer.HasSet = true;
memberIndexer.HasGet = true;

foreach (var param in method.GetParameters())
{
    memberIndexer.Parameters.Add(
        new CodeParameterDeclarationExpression(
        new CodeTypeReference(param.ParameterType), param.Name));
}

// Explicit interface declaration cannot have any modifiers
memberIndexer.Attributes = ~MemberAttributes.Private;

// add to both set/get to NotImplementedException
var exceptionStatement = new CodeThrowExceptionStatement(
    new CodeObjectCreateExpression(
        new CodeTypeReference(typeof(System.NotImplementedException)),
        new CodeExpression[] { }));
memberIndexer.GetStatements.Add(exceptionStatement);                  
memberIndexer.SetStatements.Add(exceptionStatement);

TargetClass.Members.Add(memberIndexer);
```

However, this generates the following code:

```
int IFoo.Item
{
    get
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
    set
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Any thoughts on how to do this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't do this by changing the `Name`. Instead, you should use the property that's meant exactly for this purpose: [`PrivateImplementationType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.codememberproperty.privateimplementationtype.aspx):

```
memberIndexer.PrivateImplementationType = new CodeTypeReference(iface);
```

Comment: I see.  However, then you get the entire path for the interface.  So if IFoo is part of collection.Bar.Foo, then it will print out Collection.Bar.Foo.IFoo.this[int i].  Any way around this?

Comment: @ElfsЯUs You can use `new CodeTypeReference(iface.Name)`.

Comment: That will still result in the entire name path... but I suppose I can then edit it down.